# undefined method `<<' for #<Answer::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fada31c7430>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Hi I create a controller Game to display a Q/A game

And I am blocked with `<<`, here is the code

```
def play
    lvlup(lvl)
    if lvl == 1
      set_questions
    else
      get_questions
    end
    @answers = Answer.where.not(id: question.answer_id).limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
    @answer ||= []
    @answers << question.answer
    @answers = @answers.shuffle
    render 'play'
  end
```

I create an array and I put the related answer in the global answers I want to display 4 Max.

Why does the undefined is here?

Here is the total code

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
attr_accessor :lvl

  def welcome
  end

  def congrat
  end

  def play
    lvlup(lvl)
    if lvl == 1
      set_questions
    else
      get_questions
    end
    @answers = Answer.where.not(id: question.answer_id).limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
    @answer ||= []
    @answers << question.answer
    @answers = @answers.shuffle
    render 'play'
  end

  def loose
      @question = Question.find(params[:question])
      flash.now[:alert] = "Miss..."
      render 'loose'
  end

  def check
    @lvl = params[:lvl].to_i
    answer_id = params[:id].to_i
    question = Question.find(params[:question])
    if @lvl == lvlmax
      render action: 'congrat' and return
    elsif answer_id == question.answer_id
      flash.now[:notice] = "Well done !"
      play
    else answer_id != question.answer_id
      loose
    end
  end

  private

  def lvlup(value)
    @lvl = 1 + value.to_i
  end
  def lvlmax
    @lvlmax = Question.all.count
  end

  def set_questions
    @questionsids = []
    Question.all.shuffle.each do |d|
      @questionsids << d.id
    end
    cookies[:questions] = @questionsids
  end

  def get_questions
    @questions = cookies[:questions].split('&')
  end

  def questions
    @questions = cookies[:questions]
  end

  def question
    @question = Question.find(questions[lvl])
  end

end
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mtrolle's answer might be correct, but I have my doubts as to why `ActiveRecord::Relation` was not returned as Array by default. *(Also as mentioned by BroiStatse in his comment.)*

I too noticed the same problem with my local setup however it was attributed to another issue all together. I am sharing this here in case you too happen to use MySQL.

```
Answer.where.not(id: question.answer_id).limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
```

returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. And it translates to following SQL:

```
SELECT `answers`.* FROM `answers` WHERE (id != ID) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2
```

When I try running the same in MySQL, I get:

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database.RANDOM does not exist
```

Apparently MySQL does not have `RANDOM()` function, instead it uses [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

Converting `ActiveRecord` query accordingly returned correct Array to me:

```
Answer.where.not(id: question.answer_id).limit(2).order("RAND()")
```

Comment: You mean I change `RANDOM` to `RAND`? But it breaks again an error in my code. Doest it right for you?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to append to the `@answers` result - this is an ActiveRecord relation, you cannot append data to that array.

Add `.to_a` in the end of your line where you set `@answers` to allow you to append to the array.

```
 @answers = Answer.where.not(id: question.answer_id).limit(2).order("RANDOM()").to_a
```

Comment: What is quite surprising is that Relation by default delegates missing methods to `to_a`. So why did it fail in this case?

Comment: Ok, did some digging around and it seem that this delegation is not that simple as just going with `method_missing`, as some methods needs to be delegated to relation klass. The delegation logic can be find here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a419a4d9ade48e777166ff956dd7bb24e37b2181/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb

Comment: @mtrolle I test with `to_a` and it works. Why on other code we don't use this and it works?